# Concurrent threads unable to access data in WCF ConcurrentDictionary

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, concurrency

I am facing an issue with multiple threads in a WCF service hosted on IIS.

1. The service is implemented with concurrency mode set to "multiple" and instance context mode as "per-session".
2. There is a static ConcurrentDictionary maintained in memory to store session tokens issued to incoming clients.

The problem is that sometimes threads just do not find the key stored in this dictionary and hence deny the incoming request.

I have verified that there is no unhandled exception in the flow. Log statements reveal that the problem occurs when a thread writes to the dictionary while a read operation is already underway from another thread. The issue does not reproduce when debugging using Visual Studio.

I am exploring how to leverage profiler tools to trace runtime behavior. Please suggest if there is another way to figure out exactly how the data is becoming unavailable in that dictionary.

Comment: i assume your `ConcurrentDictionary` is static ? the thing is the IIS application pool will recycle, and your dictionary goes *Puff* goneskies!

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: @TheGeneral: Yes, concurrentDictionary is static. There is no value I have specified for app pool recycle and I think default value is 29 hours. The problem appears randomly though, but definitely within an hour or so of users logging in.

Comment: You can set breakpoints in the dictionary's methods, that should work.

Comment: @hoodaticus: When I put breakpoints, I am unable to reproduce the problems.

Answer (score 0):

I had used ConcurrentDictionary for "Multiple"/"PerCall" scenario but so far did not faced any issue for concurrent read/write.

Do you have any code that remove item from your ConcurrentDictionary? Put a log there and check it is not getting called. Check your ConcurrentDictionary item count after getting error.

I guess you have looked other possibilities, such as you ensure key gets added before first access or your service host (IIS) not getting restarted in between.

Comment: Yes, keys definitely get added before accessing them. I have verified this using log statements. So, there is code which removes items from dictionary and I see that it is not called before the issue starts occurring. That piece of code dealing with removal of data, is invoked as it should be.